# How do I tell R to fill the circle dots with colour on a scatter plot?

Tags: r

I want to fill the solid circle dots on my scatterplot with colour.
I have tried this:

```
>  plot(dframe1$TV~dframe1$Books)
>  xlab="Number of books read per month"
>  plot(dframe1$TV~dframe1$Books,
          xlab="Number of books read per month")
> plot(dframe1$TV~dframe1$Books,
         xlab="Number of books read per month",
         ylab="Hours of TV watched per week",
         main="Associations between time spent watching TV and reading",
         col.main="red",
         cex=1.5,
         pch=21,
         bg=”light green”)
 Error: unexpected input in:
"pch=21,bg=”"
```

It does not work.
I would appreciate advice/help. :)

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for `? points`, which describes all the different `pch` values.

Comment: Also you're trying to pass smart (curly) quotes around `light green`. R doesn't know how to interpret them.

Comment: I think the curley-quotes were actually what threw the error because if it were the space the error message would have included the word `light` (and the leading curley-space.)

Comment: Thank you. You are probably right. I will try to be more careful. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Color name is without spaces, try `"lightgreen"` instead

Example

```
set.seed(1) # some random data
x <- rnorm(20, 5)
y <- 2 + .78*x + rnorm(20)
plot(y~x, pch=21,  bg="lightgreen")
```

which produces:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Jilber, that helps alot. :-)

Comment: Oh, just one more thing, would you mind telling me how I would underline the title in R: x<-dframe1$Books
 y<-dframe1$TV
 plot(y~x, pch=21,  bg="lightgreen")
 xlab="Number of books read per month"
plot(y~x, pch=21,  bg="lightgreen",
 xlab="Number of books read per month",
 ylab="Hours of TV watched per week",
 col.lab="darkviolet",
main="Associations between time spent watching TV and reading for students",
 col.main="coral2", cex.main=1)

Comment: Try `..., main=bquote(underline(.("Associations between time spent watching TV and reading for students")), ... And be sure to read ?plotmath and ?bquote.

Comment: Thank you DWin, it looks really good. :-) I have looked at ?plotmath, but I do not really understand ?bquote and the use of (.